# MockServer Client execution blocks on java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0

Tags: junit, mocking

I am trying to create mocks from the services needed for a system under test. I am using MockServer (mock-server.com) for that purpose. Here is code to mock the a service.

```
ClientAndServer mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);
QueryResultResponse response = new QueryResultResponse();
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String jsonStr = ow.writeValueAsString(response);
new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", 1080)
    .when(
            request()
                .withMethod("POST"),
                Times.unlimited()
            )
            .respond(
                        response()
                            .withStatusCode(200)
                                .withBody(jsonStr)
                                .withHeader(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
);
```

When I try to execute this piece of code from a JUnit rule, the thread gets blocked on  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0 and thus not able to execute the unit tests that would use this mock. Here is stack for the block call.

```
(SocketInputStream.java)  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0
        (SocketInputStream.java:152)  java.net.SocketInputStream.read
        (SocketInputStream.java:122)  java.net.SocketInputStream.read
        (LoggingInputStream.java:72)  org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read
        (SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)  org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead
        (SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)  org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer
        (SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)  org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine
        (DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)  org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead
        (DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)  org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead
        (AbstractMessageParser.java:260)  org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse
        (DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)  org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader
        (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
        (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
        (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
        (Method.java:606)  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
        (CPoolProxy.java:138)  org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke
        ()  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.receiveResponseHeader
        (HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)  org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse
        (HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)  org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute
        (MainClientExec.java:253)  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute
        (ProtocolExec.java:194)  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute
        (RetryExec.java:85)  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute
        (RedirectExec.java:108)  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute
        (InternalHttpClient.java:186)  org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute
        (CloseableHttpClient.java:82)  org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute
        (CloseableHttpClient.java:106)  org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute
        (ApacheHttpClient.java:103)  org.mockserver.client.http.ApacheHttpClient.sendPUTRequest
        (MockServerClient.java:155)  org.mockserver.client.server.MockServerClient.sendExpectation
        (ForwardChainExpectation.java:23)  org.mockserver.client.server.ForwardChainExpectation.respond
        (TestMockService.java:74)  oracle.sysman.test.unit.TestMockService.call
        (TestLoganUploadServiceUnit.java:99)  oracle.sysman.test.unit.ws.TestLoganUploadServiceUnit.startMockServer
        (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
        (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
        (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
        (Method.java:606)  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
        (FrameworkMethod.java:47)  org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall
        (ReflectiveCallable.java:12)  org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run
        (FrameworkMethod.java:44)  org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively
        (RunBefores.java:24)  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate
        (MockServerRule.java:107)  org.mockserver.junit.MockServerRule$1.evaluate
        (RunRules.java:20)  org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate
        (ParentRunner.java:271)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf
        (BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild
(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild
        (ParentRunner.java:238)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run
        (ParentRunner.java:63)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule
        (ParentRunner.java:236)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren
        (ParentRunner.java:53)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000
        (ParentRunner.java:229)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate
        (ParentRunner.java:309)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run
        (Suite.java:127)  org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild
        (Suite.java:26)  org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild
        (ParentRunner.java:238)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run
        (ParentRunner.java:63)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule
        (ParentRunner.java:236)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren
        (ParentRunner.java:53)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000
        (ParentRunner.java:229)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate
        (RunBefores.java:26)  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate
        (RunAfters.java:27)  org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate
        (ParentRunner.java:309)  org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run
        (JUnit4Testable.java:24)  oracle.jdevimpl.junit.runner.junit4.JUnit4Testable.run
        (TestExecution.java:27)  oracle.jdevimpl.junit.runner.TestExecution.run
        (JUnitTestRunner.java:93)  oracle.jdevimpl.junit.runner.JUnitTestRunner.main
```